# React admin after login should redirect to home page but it redirects to the previous url

Tags: react-admin

Actually I logedin as a superadmin having access to specific resource i.e. executives and from this page I loggedout then login with executive details who does not have access to executives page so it renders Not Found page But I want that if executive logingin and does not have access to particular url then it should redirect to dashboard page.

Comment: Show us the code so we know whats happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom saga to replace this route:

```
logoutSaga.js:

import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { replace } from 'connected-react-router'
import { UNREGISTER_RESOURCE } from 'react-admin'

function* logoutMonitor(action) {
  try {
    if (action.payload === 'name_one_your_resources') {
      yield put(replace({pathname: '/login', state: {nextPathname: '/'}})) // Replacing the route for the next entry!
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('logoutSaga:', error)
  }
}

function* logoutSaga() {
  yield takeEvery([UNREGISTER_RESOURCE], logoutMonitor) // UNREGISTER_RESOURCE - one of the last Redux Action at logout
}

export default logoutSaga
```

Connecting a custom Saga: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customsagas

Comment: No! Actually I want that whenever I login it shoul always redirect to the specific URL not the previous url when I logged out.

Comment: This is exactly what happens here, try it.